# Unity Firebase Storage Warning :FirebaseStorage.OnAppDisposed()

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

i have this warning **FirebaseStorage.OnAppDisposed()** on my app  when I integrate firebase storage in my code.

This is the information it shows:

> FirebaseStorage.OnAppDisposed()
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
> Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage(PlatformLogLevel, String) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.pKCgWTopY4/firebase/app/client/unity/src/Unity/FirebaseLogger.cs:92)
> Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage:OnAppDisposed(Object, EventArgs) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.0Ryilsblb3/firebase/storage/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseStorage.cs:114)
> Firebase.FirebaseApp:Dispose() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.teccva8Fjv/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:58)
> Firebase.FirebaseApp:Finalize() (at Z:/tmp/tmp.teccva8Fjv/firebase/app/client/unity/proxy/FirebaseApp.cs:47)

The warning does not take me to any line of my code so I don't know exactly what it refers to.
I have not found any information about this warning in firebase Docu.

Thank so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably just means .. well that `FirebaseStorage.OnAppDisposed()` was executed .. not sure if it is relevant for your app except that probably after that call you can't use Firebase anymore but to me it sounds like anyway this should being called when your app is closed / you exit PlayMode so most probably nothing to worry too much about ;)

You could turn it off by lowering the [`FirebaseStorage.LogLevel`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase#namespace_firebase_1ae165d1d7bc3d85e1c0463a2a1d9ced9a)